# Django filter queryset using a list

Tags: django, django-queryset

I have one table, table A that holds primary keys of all the objects in the table b.

if I store all the primary keys from table A in a list, then is it possible to get a list of all the objects in table B using the primary keys I have stored in a list.

For Example:

```
tableB.objects.filter(pks = list)
```

is there any way I can construct a query set like the above that would get me a list of all the object with the primary keys?

Answer (score 9):

```
tableB.objects.filter(pk__in=list)
```

Docs: https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.1/ref/models/querysets/#in